# How do I use a long password with GnuPG?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gnupg

I am using Arch Linux and GnuPG

```
Linux ryantm0j132 3.12.9-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jan 31 10:22:54 CET 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and GnuPG

```
gpg (GnuPG) 2.0.22
libgcrypt 1.6.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: ~/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECC, ?
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: MD5, SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

Using `gpg --gen-key`, it pops up a GUI dialog box that asks to enter a passphrase. How do I paste a long string of characters into the passphrase text box? I could type the long string of characters in, but I would have to do that repeatedly in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround might be to **switch to `pinentry-curses`** instead of the GUI pinentry, which offers "normal" command line pinentry (where you should be able to paste the password to). It seems [it gets installed by default on Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/pinentry/) (dependency of package `gnupg`).

To do so, modify the option `pinentry-program` in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` to `pinentry-curses`. It is also explained in the [Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG#Pinentry) and for Ubuntu linux, [I also explained how to do this (in another context) on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/424196/167385).

Alternatively, you might use another **non-interactive option for providing the password**. From `man gpg` (these are all parameters to `gpg` and you should also be able to put them into `gpg.conf`):

```
   --passphrase-fd n
          Read  the passphrase from file descriptor n. Only the first line
          will be read from file descriptor n. If you use  0  for  n,  the
          passphrase  will  be  read  from STDIN. This can only be used if
          only one passphrase is supplied.

   --passphrase-file file
          Read the passphrase from file file. Only the first line will  be
          read  from  file  file.  This  can  only  be  used  if  only one
          passphrase is supplied. Obviously, a passphrase stored in a file
          is  of  questionable security if other users can read this file.
          Don't use this option if you can avoid it.

   --passphrase string
          Use string as the passphrase. This can only be used if only  one
          passphrase  is supplied. Obviously, this is of very questionable
          security on a multi-user system. Don't use this  option  if  you
          can avoid it.
```

Comment: Changing the pinentry-program works for me.